# What's the topological dimension of Sierpiński's Triangle?

Tags: fractals

I am aware that Sierpiński's Triangle is a fractal, with Hausdorff dimension $1.5850$. Therefore my intuition leads me to believe it's topological dimension is 1 (as the topological dimension must be less than the Hausdorff dimension). However, since it's area is 0 this makes me believe it has topological dimension 0 since it's a collection of infinitely many points. Some clarification on this would be fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sierpinski triangle contains a lot of line segments so I would think its dimension would be at least 1.

There's more than one definition of topological dimension but, generally, these are inductive definitions. Loosely, we might say that a set has dimension $n$, if there is a basis for its open sets whose boundaries have dimension $n-1$. The boundaries of the open balls in $\mathbb R^3$ are spheres and the surface of a shpere has dimension 2, for example.

Of course, we need a place to start so we might define $\dim(\varnothing)=-1$. This implies that the zero dimensional sets are exactly the totally disconnected sets. In particular, any finite set in Euclidean space has dimension zero.

Now, let $T$ denote the open triangle in the plane with vertices
$$(0,0), \: (1,0), \text{ and } (1/2,\sqrt{3}/2).$$
We can obtain a basis for the open sets in the Sierpinski triangle by intersecting the Sierpinski triangle with images of $T$ under the application of functions generated by the IFS. Two such open triangles are shown in the figure below. Note that the boundary of these sets *in the Sierpinski triangle* are exactly the vertices of the smaller triangles. Thus, the basis sets have boundaries with dimension zero. So the Sierpinski triangle has dimension 1.

[image]

Comment: An excellent response. Thank you.